Python datetime object does not change date light saving automatically when setting day
I am in NZ and we just ended daylight saving on 7th April, when I change the day of the object back to before daylight saving ends, it does not update the timezone back to +13.
from django.utils import timezone

In [8]: timestamp = timezone.localtime(timezone.now())

In [9]: print(timestamp)
2024-04-09 14:20:58.907339+12:00

In [10]: timestamp = timezone.localtime(timezone.now()).replace(day=1, hour=19, minute=0, second=0)

In [11]: print(timestamp)
2024-04-01 19:00:00.784648+12:00

I have had a quick glance over this https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/02/aware-datetime-arithmetic.html but it was talking about timedelta, is this a known issue?


What's your TIME_ZONE setting?

TIME_ZONE = 'Pacific/Auckland'

Strange. Just tried locally and I get correct results with that TIME_ZONE setting: 2024-04-09 14:51:37.129818+12:00 and 2024-04-01 19:00:00.129931+13:00

What python and django version you using? Mine is 3.8 and 3.2 respectively

ok... I upgraded to python3.10 with django3.2, same problem, but once after upgraded to django4.2, the problem went away.

Thanks to @robby-cornelissen, I upgraded to Django 4.2 and the problem went away.

